# How to make text move back and forth on screen?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to some text on the screen move back and forth, so far I can only make the text move from left to right. So far, I set the text color to blue and it moves from one direction to the other and I tried making the text move back to it's original position by getting the position of the text and then passing these arguments to another function where I thought could make the text move. I tried changing some things and the closest I have gotten is when the text looks shaky, as if it was trying to move. Also any idea on how I could make the text change colors every so often?

Any help is appreciated!

```js
   var dom, x, y, finalx = 800, finaly = 0;

// ************************************************* //
// A function to initialize the x and y coordinates
//  of the current position of the text to be moved,
//  and then call the mover function

   function initText() {
      dom = document.getElementById('theText').style;

   /* Get the current position of the text */

      var x = dom.left;
      var y = dom.top;

   /* Convert the string values of left and top to
      numbers by stripping off the units */

      x = x.match(/\d+/);
      y = y.match(/\d+/);

   /* Call the function that moves it */
    moveText(x,y);


    /*** end of function initText */
}
// ************************************************* //
// A function to move the text from its original
//  position to (finalx, finaly)

   function moveText(x, y) {

      if (x != finalx)
         if (x > finalx) x--;
         else if (x < finalx) x++;

      if (y != finaly)
         if (y > finaly) y--;
         else if (y < finaly) y++;

      if ((x != finalx) || (y != finaly)) {
         dom.left = x + "px";
         dom.top = y + "px";
         setTimeout("moveText(" + x + "," + y + ")", 1);

         initText2();

       }
     }
//Move text back to original position
 function initText2(){

   var dom2, x2,y2, finalx2=100, finaly2=0;
   dom2 = document.getElementById('theText').style;

     var x2 = dom2.left;
     var y2 = dom2.top;

   /* Convert the string values of left and top to
     numbers by stripping off the units */

     x2 = x2.match(/\d+/);
     y2 = y2.match(/\d+/);
     moveTextback(x2,y2);

 }



function moveTextback(x2,y2){
  if(x2!=finalx2)
    if(x2>finalx2) x2--;
    else if (x2<finalx2)x2++;

    if(y2!=finaly2)
      if(y2>finaly2)y2--;
      else if(y2<finaly2)y2++;

    if((x2!=finalx2) || (y2!=finaly2)){
      dom2.style.left=finalx2+"px";
      dom2.style.top=finaly2+"px";
      setTimeout("moveText("+x2+","+y2+")",1);
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- moveText.html
     Illustrates a moving text element
     Uses the JavaScript from file moveText.js
     -->
<html lang = "en">
  <head>
    <title> Moving text </title>
    <meta charset = "utf-8" />
    <style type = "text/css">
      #theText {position: absolute; left: 100px; top: 100px;
                font: bold 1.7em 'Times Roman';
                color: blue;"> Save time with TIMESAVER 2.2;}
    </style>
    <script type = "text/javascript"  src = "moveText.js">
    </script>
  </head>

<!-- Call the initializing function on load, giving the
      destination coordinates for the text to be moved
      -->

  <body onload = "initText()">

<!-- The text to be moved -->
    <p>
      <span id = "theText"> Save time with TIMESAVER 2.2
      </span>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can always use a `<marquee>` element which would do this for you ;-)

Comment: Believe it or not, there's a venerable [native HTML element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/html/element/marquee) for producing this behavior with no code. If you set its `behavior` attribute to `alternate` you can also specify an `onbounce` event handler to change the text color.

Comment: @Neal `<marquee>` has been obsolete for many years.

Comment: @ScottMarcus it is still available to use in all major browsers.

Comment: @Neal And all documentation indicates that it shouldn't be used as it is obsolete and any continuing work with it has been abandoned. It's right up there with `<blink>`.

Comment: @ScottMarcus blink has actually been removed. The docs for marquee just say `Make it obsolete in favor of CSS but define its expected behavior, for backward compatibility. However, the development of the marquee features of CSS have since been abandoned.` But it has never actually been marked as obsolete :-)

Comment: @Neal It has been marked as `Obsolete`. It hasn't been marked as `deprecated`.

Comment: Either way it's not 1996 or a myspace page, `<marquee>` is dead. :D

Comment: @ChrisW. EXACTLY!

Answer (score 2):

Just css it....

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
  animation: weeee 6s linear infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes weeee {
   0% { color: red; }
  25% { color: blue; }
  50% { color: green; }
  75% { color: orange; }
 100% { transform: translateX(101%); color: purple; }
}
```

```html
<span>I AM SOME TEXT THAT MOVES BACK AND FORTH AND CHANGES COLORS AS IT GOES....WEEEEEEEE!</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished without JavaScript and using [CSS Animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations).

```css
/* Configure the animation for the element to be animated. */
p {
  animation: 5s infinite;
  animation-name: slidein;
}


/* Declare the animation. In this case, we indicate the property
   values we want at certain percentage points within the animation. */
@keyframes slidein {
  0% {
    margin-left: 0%;
    width: 300%; 
  }

  50% {
    margin-left: 90%;
    width: 10%;
    margin-top:90px; /* You can push the element up/down with this. */
    color:blue;
  }
  
  100% {
    margin-left: 0%;
    width: 300%; 
  }  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
  <head>
    <title> Moving text </title>
    <meta charset = "utf-8" />
    <style type = "text/css">
      #theText {position: absolute; left: 100px; top: 100px;
                font: bold 1.7em 'Times Roman';
                color: blue;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <!-- The text to be moved -->
    <p>Save time with TIMESAVER 2.2</p>
  </body>
</html>
```